# django model foreign key Accessing attributes of both models

Tags: django, django-orm

My code:

```
products = Clothing.objects.select_related('product')
for product in products:
   print(product.category+"  "+product.price)
```

fails with:

> AttributeError: 'Clothing' object has no attribute 'price'
>   [13/Jan/2019 13:31:53] "GET /mens_product/ HTTP/1.1" 500 65348

Comment: add your model `Cloting` and `Product`

Comment: `Clothing.objects` will give you list of `clothing` objects, not products.

Comment: I want to access attributes of both Tables Clothing and Product. Clothing has Foreign key relationship with Product. How can we achieve to access attributes of both tables using single command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a foreign key relation to `Product` in your `Clothing` model you can get all associated products by using:

`products = Product.objects.filter(clothing=a_clothing_instance)`

If you want to use a shorthand, you are probably looking for a **[RelatedManager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager)**. In a `ForeignKey` scenario you would have:

```
class Clothing(models.Model):
    ....

class Product(models.Model):
    clothing = models.ForeignKey(clothing)
```

And then you could call all products with:

`products = clothing.product_set.all()`